# Future perfect usage. Is the sentence correct?

Tags: grammar, perfect-constructions

> When will you have collected enough money?

I am talking about the time in future when you have collected enough money...

I guess future perfect should be used here.

Comment: Since you are working up to a point in time, "*By when* will you have collected enough money?" would be better. But otherwise it is OK.

Comment: You don't give enough context to show whether and why it might be important to explicitly state that the addressee must ***collect*** the necessary amount of money, but if that's *not* important, the natural phrasing is simply *When will you **have** enough money?* (or *have **got***, which in practice would be semantically equivalent). Of course, as soon as the necessary funds have been collected, the addressee "has" the money, so you could also ask *When will you collect enough money?* if you really want to focus on that aspect of *collecting* rather than simply *having/possessing*.

Comment: It's fine. Answer: By next week, next month, tomorrow. etc.

Comment: But as @user3169 there should been by in the starting.. Rest is okay

Answer (score 1):

It's a good usage of the Future Perfect. You can check yourself by making it a declarative sentence:

- You can buy a car when you will have earned enough money.
- When will you have earned enough money to buy a car?

> We use the future perfect to say that something will be finished by or at a particular time in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for wanting to use my favorite construction: the future perfect!

Yes, that is the perfect usage (no pun intended).  The time in the future when the money is collected is the time at which you will have collected the money.